# JwtSecurityTokenHandler WriteToken and 'JSON Compact serialized format string"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I'm using the JwtSecurityTokenHandler to create a JWT token.

```
#region Assembly System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll, v4.0.20622.1351
\packages\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.4.0.2.206221351\lib\net45\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll

namespace System.IdentityModel.Tokens
{
    // Summary:
    //     A System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandler designed for creating
    //     and validating Json Web Tokens. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-07.
    public class JwtSecurityTokenHandler
```

It has a method called "WriteToken" with the description as:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Writes the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken as a JSON Compact
    //     serialized format string.
    //
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken as a signed (if System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials
    //     exist) encoded string.
```

How does this get converted to a "regular" JWT that can be consumed by a client-browser and parsed?

```
        ClaimsIdentity sofCid = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>() { new Claim("MyClaimType", "MyClaimValue") }, "Custom");

        var descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = cid,
            AppliesToAddress = "http://myappliesto.com",
            SigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials( /* code that looks up the cert */),
            TokenIssuerName = "http://myissuer.com",
            Lifetime = new Lifetime(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20))
        };


        JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        SecurityToken jwt = jwtHandler.CreateToken(descriptor);

        string jsonCompactSerializedString = jwtHandler.WriteToken(jwt);
```

So when I say "normal" json, something like the below:

```
{
"isCool":true,
"favoriteColor":"green",
"rocksTheSuburbs":true,
"favoriteDecade":"80",
"isHipToBeSquare":true
}
```

or

```
{
    "iss": "jira:1314039",
    "iat": 1300819370,
    "exp": 1300819380,
    "qsh": "8063ff4ca1e41df7bc90c8ab6d0f6207d491cf6dad7c66ea797b4614b71922e9",
    "sub": "batman",
    "context": {
        "user": {
            "userKey": "batman",
            "username": "bwayne",
            "displayName": "Bruce Wayne"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to parse the payload out of the JWT, load it into an object with Json.NET, then output it again with your desired serialization settings. At the moment, I can't provide client-side code to do this, but here's how you would do it with C#:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        // Your code

        var sofCid = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim("MyClaimType", "MyClaimValue") }, "Custom");
        var descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                         {
                             Subject = sofCid,
                             AppliesToAddress = "http://myappliesto.com",
                             TokenIssuerName = "http://myissuer.com",
                             Lifetime = new Lifetime(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20))
                         };
        var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        SecurityToken jwt = jwtHandler.CreateToken(descriptor);
        string jsonCompactSerializedString = jwtHandler.WriteToken(jwt);

        // My code

        string encodedPayload = jsonCompactSerializedString.Split('.')[1];
        string decodedPayload = Base64UrlDecode(encodedPayload);
        object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(decodedPayload);
        string formattedPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject, Formatting.Indented);
    }

    // A helper method for properly base64url decoding the payload
    public static string Base64UrlDecode(string value, Encoding encoding = null)
    {
        string urlDecodedValue = value.Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');

        switch (value.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2:
                urlDecodedValue += "==";
                break;
            case 3:
                urlDecodedValue += "=";
                break;
        }

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(urlDecodedValue));
    }
}
```

Here's what `formattedPayload` looks like:

```
{
  "MyClaimType": "MyClaimValue",
  "iss": "http://myissuer.com",
  "aud": "http://myappliesto.com",
  "exp": 1468957532,
  "nbf": 1468956332
}
```

However, I would not modify the payload itself. One of the goals of the JWT format is to be as compact as possible. Adding whitespace to the payload is unnecessary and will grow the size of your token.